# How can I set gradiant background of Excel sheet row using NPOI C#?

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

Here I create one style but it doesn't work its have only some option like solid or dotted etc. background so how can I set gradient background?
Here just one stylesheet how can I set gradient background?

```
ICellStyle tablestyle = sheet.Workbook.CreateCellStyle();
tablestyle.FillForegroundColor = IndexedColors.Blue.Index;
tablestyle.FillPattern = FillPattern.AltBars;
```